# why is there a single quote in this CAT operation?

Tags: matlab, syntax, matrix

while reading someone's code I came across this:

```
data = [data.a, data.b, data.c, ...
        data.x, data.y'];
```

why does the y have a single quote after it? does it have something to do with its data type? I got this error after removing it:

```
??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

can someone please explain? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotation mark is Matlab's `transposition` operator. If `x` is a row vector then `x'` is a column vector, and so forth.

If `data.x` and `data.y` are both row vectors, it's no surprise that your attempt to horizontally concatenate `data.x` and `data.y'` is unsuccessful, it's not a well-defined operation, since the former is (I guess) a row vector and the latter (if I guess correctly) a column vector.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: to be exact, it is the "Complex conjugate transpose" same as `ctranspose`